# How to completely hide headerFragment after item selection?

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm developing an android tv based app. After selecting a header item, the list is not completely hidden. Is it possible to completely hide the part that remains visible?

I've tried using `setHeadersState(HEADERS_HIDDEN)` but it does not completely hide it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve it by setting `<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_start">260dp</dimen>` in `dimes.xml` file.